# Fill Map<String, Object> with two strings

Tags: string, dictionary, object, groovy

I want to fill my Map with two strings. For my Map I have to use <String, Object>.

Using <String, String> would instantly solve my problem, but that is not possible.

What do I need to change to make it work?:

```
Map<String, Object> myMap= [:]
myMap."foo" = "Bar"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What do I need to change to make it work?:

```
Map<String, Object> myMap= [:]
myMap."foo" = "Bar"
```

Nothing really.  That code is perfectly valid.  You could also do this:

```
Map<String, Object> myMap= [:]
myMap.foo = 'Bar'
```

Or this:

```
Map<String, Object> myMap= [foo: 'Bar']
```

And all of those will work if you change `Map<String, Object>` to `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: Thanks for the review.
I just fixed the issue. Had nothing to do with the Map!